# Looking for existing platform to 'rent' to service mms short code internationally

Tags: sms, mms

I want to offer shortcode sms and mms services to clients internationally. I've found short code providers but none offer a platform to manage the individual accounts created by each customer. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is off-topic. (Shortcodes don't work internationally (country A to B))

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Short codes are provisioned on a country-by-country basis. A short code is only able to send messages to, and receive messages from, same-country phone numbers on carrier networks that have approved the short code.